# I can access my secured site by its IP but not its domain name

Tags: apache-2.2, https

I have setup a site through Apache, let's call it `http://example.com`.  The regular site works fine and I can also access it by its IP number `http://200.x.x.x`.  I can also access the secured version at `https://200.x.x.x`.  However, `https://example.com` doesn't work and give me the following message in Firefox:

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at example.com
```

My apache configuration file for the secured site under `sites-enabled` is:

```
<VirtualHost 10.x.x.x:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.pem

    # We additionally removed HIGH security as some older MSIE browsers still can't do
    # strong crypto and they timeout
    SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3 +TLSv1
    #SSLCipherSuite SSLv3:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!SSLv2:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    WSGIDaemonProcess example.com-ssl user=www-data group=www-data processes=3
    WSGIProcessGroup example.com-ssl 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dev/project/example/apache/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

The private IP `10.x.x.x` gets mapped to `200.x.x.x`.  Does anyone know what I might be missing?  I've done the above for a few other sites and they work fine, I can't pinpoint what's wrong with the above setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever's doing the IP address translation from `200.x.x.x` to `10.x.x.x` is only doing it for port 80, not port 443.

Comment: bump for womble...I'd check my firewall to verify that you're 1) allowing port 443 into the network and 2) not specifying only port 80 in your NAT rules. Also, you didn't mention whether you had tried it or not, but if you have internal access to the server, make sure that https://example.com responds correctly to a non-firewalled request.

Comment: Port 443 is allowed in my network.  Which file do I have to check on my linux to see the ports in my NAT rules? How do I check whether example.com responds correctly to a non-firewalled request?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that SSL requires a unique IP address (not just domain name) per vhost, usually.